# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to solve an excercice and I've got to convert this

```
L = ([[4,1],[2,2],[2,"test"],[3,3],[1,"bonjour"]])
decompress (L)
```

into this

```
[1,1,1,1,2,2,"test","test",3,3,3,"bonjour"]
```

and this is how I started :

```
def por(L):
    result = []
    n = len(L)
    for i in range(n):
        m = len(L[i])
        for j in range(m):
            mult = L[j]*L[j-1]
            result.append(mult)
    return result

por([[4,1],[2,2],[2,"test"],[3,3],[1,"bonjour"]])

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
por([[4,1],[2,2],[2,"test"],[3,3],[1,"bonjour"]])
File "<pyshell#49>", line 7, in por
mult = L[j]*L[j-1]
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

I don't get what is wrong, could someone help me, it's for my exams !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def por(L):
    # add each sublist element 1  sublist element 0 times
    return [sub_list[1]  for sub in L for _ in xrange(sub_list[0])]
```

Or:

```
def por(L):
    return [ele  for times, ele in L for _ in xrange(times)]
```

Using something similar to your own code:

```
def por(L):
    result = []
    # loop over each sublist
    for sub_list in L:
        # get first sublist element and loop in that range
        times = sub_list[0] # actually accessing the first element of each sublist
        for _ in xrange(times): # use range for python 3
            # here we are adding each sublist element 1 element 0 times
            result.append(sub_list[1])
    return result
```

In your in code you are trying to multiply  `L[j]* L[j-1]` which are the both lists as you can see when you add a `print L[j],L[j-1]` in your code:

```
[4, 1] [1, 'bonjour']
[2, 2] [4, 1]
[4, 1] [1, 'bonjour']
[2, 2] [4, 1]
[4, 1] [1, 'bonjour']
[2, 2] [4, 1]
[4, 1] [1, 'bonjour']
[2, 2] [4, 1]
[4, 1] [1, 'bonjour']
[2, 2] [4, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps simplest:

```
result = []
for repetitions, contents in L:
    for _ in range(repetitions):
        result.append(contents)
```

Yes, there are better ways, some of which have already been posted, but maybe the simplicity of this one will help.

Avoiding the `len` calls and the indexing, in favor of just looping over the list and unpacking each of its items into `repetitions` and `content`, I feel contributes to the simplicity; so does building the result up from an empty list with repeated `append` calls, rather than the more idiomatic but perhaps murkier-to-a-beginner use of list comprehensions &c.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find itertools makes our life easier with these problems:

```
def por(L):
    chains = (itertools.repeat(b, a) for a, b in L)
    return list(itertools.chain_from_iterable(chains))
```

or, one one line:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain_from_iterable(itertools.repeat(b, a) for a, b in L))
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 'test', 'test', 3, 3, 3, 'bonjour']
```

Comment: It would have been nice if the arguments `a, b` were originally reversed then they would fit perfectly into `itertools.repeat`.

Comment: Try using `itertools.chain.from_iterable(chains)` instead of `itertools.chain(*chains)`, otherwise its somewhat redundant to have chains as a generator rather than a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = ([[4,1],[2,2],[2,"test"],[3,3],[1,"bonjour"]])
>>> [y for x, y in  L for i in range(x)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 'test', 'test', 3, 3, 3, 'bonjour']
```